# TeeChart Standard integration for QuickReport on DelphiXE3

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, teechart

I am moving from Delphi 2010 to Delphi XE3 and I installed QuickReport 5.
But, in Delphi XE3, i don't have the source for install the teechart graphic component for QuickReport.
In this link http://www.steema.com/download/vcl is only for Delphi XE, XE2 and XE4
Anybody, can help me with this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you consulted with the software vendor first? That should be the first place you seek help.

Comment: Actually, as I look in their support section, it explicitly says to ask questions here on StackOverflow..... But I would assume that the package for `XE2` should work in `XE3`

Answer (score 2):

I've just updated the http://www.steema.com/download/vcl page with a new entry:

- TeeChart Standard 2012 for QuickReport 5 in Delphi XE3. [Download](http://www.steema.com/files/public/QuickReport/Tee9QR5D17Std.zip)

Download the zip, extract the contents in the **compiled** folder accordingly:

- Extract **DclTee9QR5D17.bpl** to the *\RAD Studio\10.0\bin* folder in your IDE installation.
- Extract **Tee9QR5D17.bpl** to the *\Windows\System32* (for 32bit OSes) or *\Windows\SysWOW64* (for 64bit OSes) folder.
- Extract the rest of the files (*.dcu and *.dcp) to the *\RAD Studio\10.0\lib\win32\release* folder in your IDE installation.

And install the design time package (the DclTee9QR5D17.bpl package in *\RAD Studio\10.0\bin*) from the packages list in your IDE.

Comment: Yeray, thank you for your response. When I tried install, the process raises these errors: 

[dcc32 Fatal Error] QR5RunDXE3.dpk(86): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'qrwizard.pas'
[dcc32 Fatal Error] DclTee9QR5D17.dpk(35): E2202 Required package 'Tee9QR5D17' not found

Comment: I've edited the answer. Try to follow the instructions to install the compiled files instead of compiling the sources.